MySql recursive query using pivot table (many-to-many relashionship)
I'm having a huge performance issue when I run recursive query. Here is my DB Structure:
users:



id(index)
name




1
A


2
B


3
C


4
D


5
E



user_user



user_id(index)
parent_id(index)




2
1


3
2


4
2


5
4



And this is the illustration of my tree structure:

As you may realized, all users in level 3 belongs to every single user in level 2 (as same as level 5 users which belongs to every single user in level 4). The problem with this structure is that when I want to get all children which belong to user "A" a huge redundancy occurs.
Here is my query:
EXPLAIN WITH recursive `cte` AS ((
    SELECT
      `users`.id,
      1 AS `depth`,
      cast(
      `users`.`id` AS CHAR ( 65535 )) AS `path`,
      `user_user`.`parent_id` AS `pivot_parent_id`,
      `user_user`.`user_id` AS `pivot_user_id` 
    FROM
      `users`
      INNER JOIN `user_user` ON `users`.`id` = `user_user`.`user_id` 
    WHERE
      `user_user`.`parent_id` = 4) UNION ALL
    (
    SELECT
      `users`.id,
      `depth` + 1 AS `depth`,
      concat( `path`, 4, `users`.`id` ),
      `user_user`.`parent_id` AS `pivot_parent_id`,
      `user_user`.`user_id` AS `pivot_user_id` 
    FROM
      `users`
      INNER JOIN `user_user` ON `users`.`id` = `user_user`.`user_id`
      INNER JOIN `cte` ON `cte`.`id` = `user_user`.`parent_id` 
    )) SELECT DISTINCT
  `id` 
FROM
  `cte`

And the result of Explain:

The above query takes 5 minutes to finish. Any suggestion to optimize the query?

Please include the results of explain and list of all indexes with the columns in them for all involved tables.

@Shadow I've updated my question.

Please add the result of the explain as well

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/using-explain.html

I think you should add a limit  to depth + 1. What is the maximum depth? Or if you don't know/have the maximum value, just try with any value. Maybe WHERE depth + 1 < 100.

@FanoFN The depth is dynamic. It might increase based on the structure. I think depth is not the problem. The problem is having multiple parents by users which has a lot of children themselves causing redundancy in query.

@Shadow Explain is added

Whay do you join users table in recursive query? Better join this table with cte result.

What is the count of the final output? Each level/depth and its width is going to add significantly to the output. In your diagram it's only 16 nodes input, but the output is (1x3)+(1x3X4)+(1x3x4x4)+(1x3x4x4x4)=255 which is not going to scale well. Perhaps, knowing that every level owns every node beneath it, there is a better path to solving.

That being said, I can't think of a way of writing recursive cte logic that would say "Only run the next leg of recursion on the first child" since window functions aren't allowed in CTEs, nor is more than one reference to the recursive term allowed; both of which are the only patterns I can think to write that. This might be one of those things that is sufficiently complicated enough that doing it procedurally might be warranted so you can control what child you query for the next iteration.

@JNevill For instance, On the 3rd level, the width is 31, every one of this 31 users has ~250 children. Actually this levels are defined as groups while every group has only ONE parent.
